# Extract the first two characters of names in a list and concatenating into a string?

Tags: python

I have a list

```
names = ['John', 'Ralph', 'Frank', 'Luke', 'David', 'Helen', 'Chloe', 'Sophia']
```

I want to take the first two letters and combine them together 
such as:

```
JoRaFrLuDaHeChSo
```

I found the code below that does a similar job and I added [:2] to get the first two letters however it doesn't work.

```
print("".join([str(x) for x in names[:2]))
```

Comment: you are slicing the list rather than strings

Answer (score 4):

You put the slice in the wrong place. Also, the names are already strings, you don't need `str()`.

```
print("".join([x[:2] for x in names]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, the list slicing needs to be done on the string, not the original list.

```
my_string = "".join([x[:2] for x in names])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also qvoid syntax if you like:

```
names = ['John', 'Ralph', 'Frank', 'Luke', 'David', 'Helen', 'Chloe', 'Sophia']

# import the needed standard functions
from itertools import islice, repeat, chain

# take 2 initial characters of each string
prefixes = map(islice, names, repeat(2))

# chain prefixes
concatenated = chain.from_iterable(prefixes)

# join to one string
result = ''.join(concatenated)
```